# How increase autoload performance

Tags: php, json, performance

I Have a platform writen in PHP, and store a class definition in each file in following way:

```
filename.php = lower(<class name>) + ".php"
```

I also use autoload functions to get class name and, using a json generated file (by a custom tool that I made), load the especific file that contains the class definition (I tried to use blob before this, but is too slow).

**Why a generated file?** Because doing a file search on diretory tree in every request to find the corresponding class is IO intensive.

my generated json class map:

```
{
    "homecontroller": "path/to/dir/homecontroller.php",
    "database": "path/to/another/deep/dir/database.php"
}
```

Today this process of loading json, decoding and store in a array to use in autoload to find classes takes arround 30~50 milliseconds.

autoload, using the generated json class map:

```
$_runtimefile = "packages/.runtime-map";
$classmap = json_decode(file_get_contents($_runtimefile));;
function __autoload($classname)
{
    global $classmap;

    $classidentifier = mb_strtolower($classname);
    if(!array_key_exists($classidentifier, $classmap)) return;

    $filename = __DIR__ . "/" . $classmap->{$classidentifier};
    if(!file_exists($filename))
    {
        debug_print_backtrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("File {$filename} not found for class {$classname}");
    }
    require_once($filename);
}
```

But I want **to do this in a better way, in performance point of view**. What are the better ways to load/have a class mapping or autoload for large projects and how I can do this?

Additional informations:

- The project has arround 300 classes.
- Currently, a simple request takes a minimum of 30~50 milliseconds in localhost.

Comment: Are you sure that autoload is your bottleneck?

Comment: yes, a simple php file with echo takes less than 3~5 milliseconds to respond

Comment: Why use json for your classmap and not a PHP array? then you could skip the json_decode. Why are you using `mb_strtolower()`? Do your classnames really contain non-ASCII characters? Si this really the biggest bottleneck in your system? Have you profiled your code?

Comment: Try measuring the sum of the time spent on your autoload script using php's `microtime()` if it really represent a so high time, break it into pieces to check what piece consumes more time

Comment: Is your code running under localhost or production? SSD drives will improve a lot your performance if you load many files.

Comment: You cal also reduce your autoload script, remove the strlower part, store the class name as it is. Also checking if file exists is redundancy, since require will throw an exception anyway if the file is missing.

Comment: Store your class map as an PHP array, and require into a variable instead of parsing a json

Comment: @EliasSoares both localhost and production are SSD, but this isn't tottaly about the project bottleneck, yes there is another points that I can improve (the entire response in production takes 200~300 milliseconds to TTFB including network, database, encryption and other code), but I want to improve this code in specific, find better wyas to load classes

Comment: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Comment: Try using a ready to use autoload. Use psr0 standard so you do not need to store a class map (one less file to require)

Comment: the psr0 standard looks good, I didn't know before, can you made a answer with it? thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, there is no non-ASCII characters in class names, iwill replace to strtolower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions of Elias Soares and Mark Baker I rewrite my code to use file mapping based on a php array.

To create and recreate the php automatically I create d a little C# console program that works fine on my project.

Answer (score 1):

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) can do it right out of the box - building a list of all classes within one or more sub-directories.

When it comes to actually autoloading them, there are also a number of optional optimisations that can be used to cache the [(non-)existence of files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md) so that further checks will not be required.  These optimisations would almost always only be useful in production, where deployment is controlled.

Comment: yes, composer is a option to replace the php array that I created, but now the application runs fine and performance is great... for my solution composer is not necessary and don't apply, but is a great option for future cases